# Minimum number of data points for RMS

Tags: statistics

In calculating the rms of a group of data points, what is the smallest number of points needed to get a meaningful rms value? Specifically I'm looking at audio files and using an rms value for a small period as a measure of the sound energy for that period. Basically I'm wondering what the lower bound for my period is before the measure gets too uncertain.